Apache camel with spring boot on-exception redelivery counter reset behavior
I am working on an apache camel (version 4.3.0) migration project in spring boot(3.2.1) and java 17. I don't want my camel route to send any camel related headers to the downstream application when it posts a message to their queue. However, when the message publishing to the downstream queue fails due to some reason, I want to retry. Below is the code snippet.
The issue is if I use a route level exception handler (doTry..doCatch) in which I publish the message (or throw the exception to mimic a failure) along with the global onException handler, the failure retry happens infinitely because the entire route gets executed again and again and the camel redelivery tracking headers gets removed/reset and stays at 1 always in every iteration.
But if I don't wrap the exception throwing logic inside the route level exception handler (doTry..doCatch..) and retains only the global exception handler, only the retry for the failed step happens repeats and the retries happen and finishes properly.
Question: Why is the entire route retried in case the failure code is wrapped in a doTry..doCatch instead of retrying the failed step alone (like when there's no doTry..doCatch)?
package com.apache.camel.test_exception;

import org.apache.camel.LoggingLevel;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ExceptionTest extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        
        onException(Exception.class)
            .handled(true)          
            .log("Caught exception")
            .maximumRedeliveries(3)
            .redeliveryDelay(3000)
            .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN)
            .retriesExhaustedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN)
            .log("Exception Handled")
        .end();
        
        restConfiguration().component("servlet").scheme("http").port(8080);
        
        rest("/service/api/v1")
            .get("/testException")
            .routeId("rest-exception")
            .to("direct:exceptionRoute");
        
        from("direct:exceptionRoute")
            .routeId("exception-route")
            .log("Received request to test exception")
            //.doTry()
                .removeHeaders("Camel*")
                .log("Headers:${headers}")
                .throwException(new ClassCastException())//Send to target application queue in real scenario which will result in an exception as the broker is down and will result in a retry     
            //.doCatch(NullPointerException.class)
                .log("NullPointer Exception Caught")
            //.endDoTry()
            .log("Route ended")
        .end();                         
    }
}

Logs with doTry..doCatch and onException handler enabled
2024-12-14T21:32:47.248+05:30  INFO 21048 --- [test-exception] [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 4.3.0 (camel-1) started in 13ms (build:0ms init:0ms start:13ms)
2024-12-14T21:32:47.251+05:30  INFO 21048 --- [test-exception] [           main] c.a.c.t.TestExceptionApplication         : Started TestExceptionApplication in 3.352 seconds (process running for 3.788)
2024-12-14T21:32:54.867+05:30  INFO 21048 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Received request to test exception
2024-12-14T21:32:54.871+05:30  INFO 21048 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Headers:{accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br, zstd, accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.9,en-IN;q=0.8, cache-control=max-age=0, connection=keep-alive, host=localhost:8080, sec-ch-ua="Microsoft Edge";v="131", "Chromium";v="131", "Not_A Brand";v="24", sec-ch-ua-mobile=?0, sec-ch-ua-platform="Windows", sec-fetch-dest=document, sec-fetch-mode=navigate, sec-fetch-site=none, sec-fetch-user=?1, upgrade-insecure-requests=1, user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/131.0.0.0}
2024-12-14T21:32:54.877+05:30  WARN 21048 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for (MessageId: F19F1F2933548D7-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: F19F1F2933548D7-0000000000000000). On delivery attempt: 0 caught: java.lang.ClassCastException
2024-12-14T21:32:57.883+05:30  WARN 21048 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for (MessageId: F19F1F2933548D7-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: F19F1F2933548D7-0000000000000000). On delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.ClassCastException
2024-12-14T21:33:00.896+05:30  WARN 21048 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for (MessageId: F19F1F2933548D7-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: F19F1F2933548D7-0000000000000000). On delivery attempt: 2 caught: java.lang.ClassCastException
2024-12-14T21:33:03.897+05:30  WARN 21048 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for (MessageId: F19F1F2933548D7-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: F19F1F2933548D7-0000000000000000). On delivery attempt: 3 caught: java.lang.ClassCastException
2024-12-14T21:33:03.899+05:30  INFO 21048 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Caught exception
2024-12-14T21:33:03.900+05:30  INFO 21048 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Exception Handled
Logs with doTry..doCatch disabled, only onException handler enabled
0024 --- [test-exception] [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 4.3.0 (camel-1) started in 13ms (build:0ms init:0ms start:13ms)
2024-12-14T21:37:33.981+05:30  INFO 10024 --- [test-exception] [           main] c.a.c.t.TestExceptionApplication         : Started TestExceptionApplication in 3.266 seconds (process running for 3.675)
2024-12-14T21:37:42.252+05:30  INFO 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Received request to test exception
2024-12-14T21:37:42.257+05:30  INFO 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Headers:{accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br, zstd, accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.9,en-IN;q=0.8, cache-control=max-age=0, connection=keep-alive, host=localhost:8080, sec-ch-ua="Microsoft Edge";v="131", "Chromium";v="131", "Not_A Brand";v="24", sec-ch-ua-mobile=?0, sec-ch-ua-platform="Windows", sec-fetch-dest=document, sec-fetch-mode=navigate, sec-fetch-site=none, sec-fetch-user=?1, upgrade-insecure-requests=1, user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/131.0.0.0}
2024-12-14T21:37:42.260+05:30  WARN 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for (MessageId: 2D33F0C9EC05105-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: 2D33F0C9EC05105-0000000000000000). On delivery attempt: 0 caught: java.lang.ClassCastException
2024-12-14T21:37:45.262+05:30  INFO 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Received request to test exception
2024-12-14T21:37:45.263+05:30  INFO 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Headers:{accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br, zstd, accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.9,en-IN;q=0.8, cache-control=max-age=0, connection=keep-alive, host=localhost:8080, sec-ch-ua="Microsoft Edge";v="131", "Chromium";v="131", "Not_A Brand";v="24", sec-ch-ua-mobile=?0, sec-ch-ua-platform="Windows", sec-fetch-dest=document, sec-fetch-mode=navigate, sec-fetch-site=none, sec-fetch-user=?1, upgrade-insecure-requests=1, user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/131.0.0.0}
2024-12-14T21:37:45.263+05:30  WARN 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for (MessageId: 2D33F0C9EC05105-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: 2D33F0C9EC05105-0000000000000000). On delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.ClassCastException
2024-12-14T21:37:48.264+05:30  INFO 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Received request to test exception
2024-12-14T21:37:48.264+05:30  INFO 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Headers:{accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br, zstd, accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.9,en-IN;q=0.8, cache-control=max-age=0, connection=keep-alive, host=localhost:8080, sec-ch-ua="Microsoft Edge";v="131", "Chromium";v="131", "Not_A Brand";v="24", sec-ch-ua-mobile=?0, sec-ch-ua-platform="Windows", sec-fetch-dest=document, sec-fetch-mode=navigate, sec-fetch-site=none, sec-fetch-user=?1, upgrade-insecure-requests=1, user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/131.0.0.0}
2024-12-14T21:37:48.265+05:30  WARN 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for (MessageId: 2D33F0C9EC05105-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: 2D33F0C9EC05105-0000000000000000). On delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.ClassCastException
2024-12-14T21:37:51.266+05:30  INFO 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Received request to test exception
2024-12-14T21:37:51.266+05:30  INFO 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Headers:{accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br, zstd, accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.9,en-IN;q=0.8, cache-control=max-age=0, connection=keep-alive, host=localhost:8080, sec-ch-ua="Microsoft Edge";v="131", "Chromium";v="131", "Not_A Brand";v="24", sec-ch-ua-mobile=?0, sec-ch-ua-platform="Windows", sec-fetch-dest=document, sec-fetch-mode=navigate, sec-fetch-site=none, sec-fetch-user=?1, upgrade-insecure-requests=1, user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/131.0.0.0}
2024-12-14T21:37:51.267+05:30  WARN 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for (MessageId: 2D33F0C9EC05105-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: 2D33F0C9EC05105-0000000000000000). On delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.ClassCastException
2024-12-14T21:37:54.267+05:30  INFO 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Received request to test exception
2024-12-14T21:37:54.267+05:30  INFO 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Headers:{accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br, zstd, accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.9,en-IN;q=0.8, cache-control=max-age=0, connection=keep-alive, host=localhost:8080, sec-ch-ua="Microsoft Edge";v="131", "Chromium";v="131", "Not_A Brand";v="24", sec-ch-ua-mobile=?0, sec-ch-ua-platform="Windows", sec-fetch-dest=document, sec-fetch-mode=navigate, sec-fetch-site=none, sec-fetch-user=?1, upgrade-insecure-requests=1, user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/131.0.0.0}
2024-12-14T21:37:54.268+05:30  WARN 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for (MessageId: 2D33F0C9EC05105-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: 2D33F0C9EC05105-0000000000000000). On delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.ClassCastException
2024-12-14T21:37:57.269+05:30  INFO 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Received request to test exception
2024-12-14T21:37:57.269+05:30  INFO 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Headers:{accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br, zstd, accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.9,en-IN;q=0.8, cache-control=max-age=0, connection=keep-alive, host=localhost:8080, sec-ch-ua="Microsoft Edge";v="131", "Chromium";v="131", "Not_A Brand";v="24", sec-ch-ua-mobile=?0, sec-ch-ua-platform="Windows", sec-fetch-dest=document, sec-fetch-mode=navigate, sec-fetch-site=none, sec-fetch-user=?1, upgrade-insecure-requests=1, user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/131.0.0.0}
2024-12-14T21:37:57.270+05:30  WARN 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for (MessageId: 2D33F0C9EC05105-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: 2D33F0C9EC05105-0000000000000000). On delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.ClassCastException
2024-12-14T21:38:00.271+05:30  INFO 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Received request to test exception
2024-12-14T21:38:00.272+05:30  INFO 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Headers:{accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br, zstd, accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.9,en-IN;q=0.8, cache-control=max-age=0, connection=keep-alive, host=localhost:8080, sec-ch-ua="Microsoft Edge";v="131", "Chromium";v="131", "Not_A Brand";v="24", sec-ch-ua-mobile=?0, sec-ch-ua-platform="Windows", sec-fetch-dest=document, sec-fetch-mode=navigate, sec-fetch-site=none, sec-fetch-user=?1, upgrade-insecure-requests=1, user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/131.0.0.0}

2024-12-14T21:38:00.273+05:30  WARN 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for (MessageId: 2D33F0C9EC05105-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: 2D33F0C9EC05105-0000000000000000). On delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.ClassCastException
2024-12-14T21:38:03.275+05:30  INFO 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Received request to test exception
2024-12-14T21:38:03.276+05:30  INFO 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Headers:{accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br, zstd, accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.9,en-IN;q=0.8, cache-control=max-age=0, connection=keep-alive, host=localhost:8080, sec-ch-ua="Microsoft Edge";v="131", "Chromium";v="131", "Not_A Brand";v="24", sec-ch-ua-mobile=?0, sec-ch-ua-platform="Windows", sec-fetch-dest=document, sec-fetch-mode=navigate, sec-fetch-site=none, sec-fetch-user=?1, upgrade-insecure-requests=1, user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/131.0.0.0}
2024-12-14T21:38:03.276+05:30  WARN 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for (MessageId: 2D33F0C9EC05105-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: 2D33F0C9EC05105-0000000000000000). On delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.ClassCastException
2024-12-14T21:38:06.277+05:30  INFO 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Received request to test exception
2024-12-14T21:38:06.278+05:30  INFO 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Headers:{accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br, zstd, accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.9,en-IN;q=0.8, cache-control=max-age=0, connection=keep-alive, host=localhost:8080, sec-ch-ua="Microsoft Edge";v="131", "Chromium";v="131", "Not_A Brand";v="24", sec-ch-ua-mobile=?0, sec-ch-ua-platform="Windows", sec-fetch-dest=document, sec-fetch-mode=navigate, sec-fetch-site=none, sec-fetch-user=?1, upgrade-insecure-requests=1, user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/131.0.0.0}
2024-12-14T21:38:06.279+05:30  WARN 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for (MessageId: 2D33F0C9EC05105-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: 2D33F0C9EC05105-0000000000000000). On delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.ClassCastException
2024-12-14T21:38:09.281+05:30  INFO 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Received request to test exception
2024-12-14T21:38:09.281+05:30  INFO 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Headers:{accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br, zstd, accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.9,en-IN;q=0.8, cache-control=max-age=0, connection=keep-alive, host=localhost:8080, sec-ch-ua="Microsoft Edge";v="131", "Chromium";v="131", "Not_A Brand";v="24", sec-ch-ua-mobile=?0, sec-ch-ua-platform="Windows", sec-fetch-dest=document, sec-fetch-mode=navigate, sec-fetch-site=none, sec-fetch-user=?1, upgrade-insecure-requests=1, user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/131.0.0.0}
2024-12-14T21:38:09.282+05:30  WARN 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for (MessageId: 2D33F0C9EC05105-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: 2D33F0C9EC05105-0000000000000000). On delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.ClassCastException
2024-12-14T21:38:12.283+05:30  INFO 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Received request to test exception
2024-12-14T21:38:12.283+05:30  INFO 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Headers:{accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br, zstd, accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.9,en-IN;q=0.8, cache-control=max-age=0, connection=keep-alive, host=localhost:8080, sec-ch-ua="Microsoft Edge";v="131", "Chromium";v="131", "Not_A Brand";v="24", sec-ch-ua-mobile=?0, sec-ch-ua-platform="Windows", sec-fetch-dest=document, sec-fetch-mode=navigate, sec-fetch-site=none, sec-fetch-user=?1, upgrade-insecure-requests=1, user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/131.0.0.0}
2024-12-14T21:38:12.283+05:30  WARN 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for (MessageId: 2D33F0C9EC05105-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: 2D33F0C9EC05105-0000000000000000). On delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.ClassCastException
2024-12-14T21:38:15.285+05:30  INFO 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Received request to test exception
2024-12-14T21:38:15.285+05:30  INFO 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] exception-route                          : Headers:{accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br, zstd, accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.9,en-IN;q=0.8, cache-control=max-age=0, connection=keep-alive, host=localhost:8080, sec-ch-ua="Microsoft Edge";v="131", "Chromium";v="131", "Not_A Brand";v="24", sec-ch-ua-mobile=?0, sec-ch-ua-platform="Windows", sec-fetch-dest=document, sec-fetch-mode=navigate, sec-fetch-site=none, sec-fetch-user=?1, upgrade-insecure-requests=1, user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/131.0.0.0}
2024-12-14T21:38:15.286+05:30  WARN 10024 --- [test-exception] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for (MessageId: 2D33F0C9EC05105-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: 2D33F0C9EC05105-0000000000000000). On delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.ClassCastException
PS : This issue is not observed with camel 4.9.0 as the exception is neither caught by doTry..doCatch nor the onException handler. I have posted a different question for that for experts to answer.
Apache Camel with spring boot, retry behavior difference on exception
